# Iterate through list(locals().keys())?

Tags: python, list, loops, parameters

I'm trying to iterate through the list of the parameters of a function.

When I write `for item in list(locals().keys()):` it says `invalid syntax`

Can anyone help?

EDIT: here's more of my code

```
def enterData(name, symptoms = None, nicknames = None):
  print(list(locals().keys())
  for item in list(locals().keys()):
    if item == None:
      pass
    else:
      pass # do something eventually

enterData(name = "Hirschsprung disease", nicknames = "Congenital megacolon")
```

Comment: please share more code and examlpe when excactly do you get it? ...

Comment: Please show your whole code. If you only have this line, the invalid syntax is right. You need to do something with item in the next line.

Comment: How about `for key in locals():...` ?

Answer (score 1):

You must describe what to do with "item", like so:

```
for item in list(locals().keys()):
    print(item)
```